# Why is document.getElementById not properly getting the value of a text area?

Tags: javascript

When I try to use document.getElementById to get the value of a text area, it returns [object HTMLTextAreaElement]. How can I fix this?
This is my code:

```
<html>
<textarea id = "inputbox">test</textarea>
<p id = "outputbox"></p>
<script>
var test1 = document.getElementById("inputbox");
function test(){
    document.getElementById("outputbox").innerHTML = test1;
}
test();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Because `getElementById`, as it sounds, returns an element. If you want the element's value, you have to access its `value` property

Comment: Google getElementById and see if you can refine your question with the knowledge you found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use value property after getting element by id

```
document.getElementById("outputbox").innerHTML = test1.value;
```